# Web Applications terminate strings on null-byte

Tags: web-application, php, asp.net

I have just been doing some penetration testing on a site, and I have noticed (and I have noticed before but now seems like a good point to bring it up) that putting a null byte in the search string actually terminates the string there.

That is fine for the lower level languages like C, I know how that works, but why does this apply to the web applications, I have seen this happen in both PHP and ASPX pages.

Is this a vulnerability, an intended feature of the language or just a bug with the languages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually PHP strings can contain null bytes; so can a .NET string (hence ASP.NET). At the PHP level, this byte is nothing special; the character U+0000 is just another Unicode code point. Trouble begins when the string is passed to another system, for which the null byte is a string terminator. In particular for file accesses: if the PHP code tries to open the file `foo.txt\0.php` (where `\0` stands for a null byte), then the OS will only see a request for `foo.txt`, ignoring the rest of the string.

[This is documented.](http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php) [In other languages as well.](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte)

In your case, one must assume that the bytes received as a "search string" are sent *unmodified* to an underlying search system for which the null byte has the special meaning of terminating the string. Though this is not a vulnerability in its own right, it is indicative of the Web site not filtering input characters, and *that* can lead to trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer, so if they aren't filtering null-bytes, what else might they not be filtering I guess is the next game. Thanks!

Comment: [*that* can lead to trouble](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2013/09/modsecurity-xss-evasion-challenge-results.html) ... yes yes :)